# array.Contains() on Jagged array

Tags: c#, linq, multidimensional-array, jagged-arrays

I want to check if a sub array contains a value without using a loop.

I need to see if `example[*][1]` contains a certain value.
Something like this:

```
string[][] example = new string[2][];
example[0][0] = "category1";
example[0][1] = "123";
example[1][0] = "category2";
example[1][1] = "456";
bool exists = example[*][1].Contains("456");
```

Comment: It's a `Jagged array` BTW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about...

```
bool exists = example.Any(i=>i.Contains("456"));
```

Comment: `example.Any(i => i[1] == "456")` did it for me, thanks!